# New Feature Popup Causes Bad UX On Cookie-less Browsers

Tags: bug, feature-request

I use a browser setup which does not persist cookies for domains that I don't whitelist. This isn't too uncommon of a setup, I use an addon called [Temporary Container Tabs for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/temporary-containers/) with 14,000 users.

The problem is that every time I navigate to a Stack Exchange site this popup about some new feature obscures the answer I am trying to view. I keep having to dismiss the popup every time I visit Stack Exchange.

I would appreciate if this "new feature tour popup" did not exist. Generally Stack Exchange has been a site which avoids popups that show without user interaction. As generally this is considered to be an annoying pattern.

I do see the value of a "new feature tour" popup from a product perspective. But I also feel like currently it is diminishing the experience. I would love it if there could be some modification to the design. I see that there is already a small yellow indicator next to the new feature. Maybe the popup could only pop up if you click on that?

[image: Screenshot of website tour popup]

Comment: This also affects users who use multiple devices.  Perhaps this setting (and maybe the sort order?) could be stored server-side.

Comment: There are billions of people on the planet, I would argue that 14000 is indeed not uncommon, it is in fact rarely used. This still gets my upvote because I simply fully agree with the statement *I would appreciate if this "new feature tour popup" did not exist*. Give me a "don't nag me" configuration option, please.